# Using dynamic WHERE clause with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I can not get dynamic where clause working. The query I use:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.tables
                WHERE   name = 'a' )
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE a ( a INT );

    END;
DECLARE @whereClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' 1=1 ';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE @whereClause';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@whereClause NVARCHAR(MAX)', @whereClause;

DROP TABLE a;
```

Then additional question would be: is there any possibility to debug query that is executed with  sl_executesql?

Comment: one way is to Print the query before executing it. You can do that by just doing PRINT @sql

Comment: You can't use part of SQL statement as parameter. You could build entire statement beforehand (`set @sql = 'select ... where ' +  @where`), but this is bad idea anyway (I like clauses like `1=0 ; drop table a --`) :)

Comment: You can't pass a part of the query as a variable. Construct your query dynamically including the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

As as been stated you can't use the parameters on `sp_executesql` to replace statement objects, only parameter variables.

If you need to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically, I find it easier to use `REPLACE` for the Object components of the statement.

```
DECLARE @whereClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' 1=@whereVariable ';
DECLARE @whereVariable INT = 1;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE @whereClause';

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@whereClause', @whereClause)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    ,'@whereVariable INT'
    ,@whereVariable = @whereVariable;
```

This means that the statement can be built without interlived `+` and variables. It then means that the input and output parameters are used as normal.